# spark sql unable to read delta lake table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, delta-lake

has anyone ran into this error while reading a delta lake table using spark.sql??

I am running spark on an EMR and using S3 to store my tables. I am able to create the DB and tables to read from my S3 location. However, it's when i try to query the table, i constantly run into this error. When I create non delta tables, I am able to query using spark.sql just fine. This error is specific to querying delta tables.

ERROR -----

```
An error was encountered:
Table does not support reads: poc.contact
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 485, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table does not support reads: poc.contact
```

summary of commands I am using on jupyter notebook->

```
import pyspark.sql

%%configure -f
{
  "conf": {
    "spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0",
    "spark.sql.extensions": "io.delta.sql.DeltasparkSessionExtension",
    "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog": "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
  }
}

from delta.tables import *

df1 = spark.read.csv('s3://.../raw/contact.csv',header=True)

df1.write.format("delta").save("s3://.../staging/contact")

spark.sql('create database poc')

spark.sql('use poc')

spark.sql("CREATE TABLE poc.contacts USING DELTA LOCATION 's3://.../staging/contact'")

spark.sql("show tables").show()
#shows table

spark.sql("select count(*) from poc.contact")
#ERROR
```

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet?  Additional details including the location of files, other queries that work, etc would help.  "I am able to query using spark.sql just fine. This error is specific to querying delta tables" is confusing because you can query Delta Tables with Spark SQL.

Comment: added commands I am using on jupyter notebook. Thank you!

Comment: That's a really old Delta version.  What Spark version are you using?  Here's the Delta Lake / Spark compatibility matrix: https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html